# Toggle div to scale up and slide left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to alter an already existing piece of javascript that was born on stackoverflow but I don't know how...

```
$('.menuBtn').click(function(event) {
value = $('.whole').css('right') === '100px' ? 0 : '100px';
  $('.whole').animate({
      right: value
  });
```

This is the link to the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bayron2304/Abs5H/1189/

I've already changed it a little in terms of width and placement. But what I now need is that the blue div, before it slides to the left, to scale up and create a drop shadow (giving the effect of the blue box coming towards you. aka 3d, understand?).

fast summary of the animation:

- click box > box get's bigger (let's say 10% bigger) and creates drop shadow > then about 500ms wait > slide to left and reveal what's underneath.

then when the box get's clicked again the whole animation starts over but backwards. A toggle.

Hopefully someone can help me because I really need it. Thanks!

Comment: something like http://jsfiddle.net/link2pk/Abs5H/1193/ ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.menuBtn').click(function(event) {
    value = $('.whole').css('right') === '100px' ? 0 : '100px';
     $('.whole').addClass('scaleUp');
      $('.whole').delay(1000).animate({
          right: value
      });
});

.scaleUp{
 transition-duration:.5s;
 box-shadow:2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  transform:scale(1.2);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me... Could you add a JSFiddle maybe? Thanks

Comment: What am I doing wrong here? Reminder, I'm a total noob to javascript etc. http://jsfiddle.net/bayron2304/Abs5H/1192/

Comment: you could just use toggle() to add remove a class and set transition within the CSS http://jsfiddle.net/Abs5H/1194/ ;)

Comment: Thanks GCYrillus, with a little bit of tweaking it looks like what I was after! Again, thanks for the help!